# Cannot found DeleteObject log in CloudTrail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, logging, amazon-cloudtrail

I made 'data-event-test-bucket'and 'cloudtrail-log-bucket'. I created trails using data events option.

[test 1]

I uploaded test.txt file to 'data-event-test-bucket' in console and I deleted test.txt file in console. I guess I could find 'PutObject' and 'DeleteObject' log.

But I couldn't find 'DeleteObject' log. I could only find 'PutObject' and etc log.

I don't know why there are no 'DeleteObject' record.

```
---------Test 1 Logs - eventname----------
GetBucketEncryption
PutObject
GetBucketObjecLockConfiguration
HeadObject
HeadObject
GetObjectAcl
GetBucketObjectLockConfiguration
----------------------------------------------------.
```

[test 2]

I uploaded test.txt file to 'data-event-test-bucket' in CLI and I deleted test.txt file in CLI. I guess I could find 'PutObject' and 'DeleteObject' log. I could find 'DeleteObject', 'PutObject' and etc log.

Why is there no 'DeleteObject' record when I delete s3 object from the console?

Please tell me how to log when I delete an object from the console.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/find-cloudtrail-object-level-events/)?

Comment: @Marcin this?? What does it mean?